# Garbage Collection of Looping statements in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, garbage-collection, nested-loops

Nowadays, I'm participating in few competitions in codegolf. For a particular question. I've submitted an answer in java which contains Nested loops like this.

```
for(int i=0; i < 20_00_00_000; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < 10_00_000; j++){
        //declare some variables
        //do operations
        //modify variables outside of for loop
    }
}
```

Assume this takes `n` time.

Another member posted a similar answer but like this.

```
for(int i=0; i < 20_00_00_000; i++){
    nextLoop(pass necessary args);
}

private void nextLoop(necessary args){
    for(int j=0; j < 10_00_000; j++){
        //declare some variables
        //do operations
        //modify variables outside of for loop
    }
}
```

But this takes only 60% of `n` time. then I realised it would be related to Garbase collection of the nested loops. The logic of both codes were the same, but seperating the inner loop into a method makes it more faster. I assume this is because Garbage collection is happening once the `nextLoop()` method finishes but there is a problem in Garbage collection regarding First code's nested for loops.

Now regarding first code, does the memory taken by inner for loop won't be automatically garbage collected once the next iteration of parent loop starts?

### REAL CODE

**Method 2 (Faster)**

```
public class MinPrimeFactorSum {

    static int[] primes = new int[20_000_000];
    static int count = 0;

    static int temp;
    static int p;
    static long total = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int i=3;
        for(; i<1_00_00_000; i += 2) {
            // Calling the inner loop as a method
            temp = getData(i);
            if( i == temp ) {
                primes[count] = temp;
                count++;
            }
            total += temp + 2;
        }
        System.out.println( --i + ": " + total + " in " + (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000000 + " milliseconds" );
    }

    // Inner Loop as a method
    private static int getData(int i) {
        temp = i;
        for(int index = 0;index < count; index++ ) {
            p = primes[index];
            if( i % p == 0 ) {
                temp = p;
                break;
            }
            if( p > Math.sqrt(i) ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

}
```

**Method 1 (Slower)**

```
public class MinPrimeFactorSum {

    static int[] primes = new int[20_000_000];
    static int count = 0;

    static int temp;
    static int p;
    static long total = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int i=3;
        for(; i<1_00_00_000; i += 2) {
            temp = i;

            // Inner Loop Starts
            for(int index = 0;index < count; index++ ) {
                p = primes[index];
                if( i % p == 0 ) {
                    temp = p;
                    break;
                }
                if( p > Math.sqrt(i) ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Inner Loop ends

            if( i == temp ) {
                primes[count] = temp;
                count++;
            }
            total += temp + 2;
        }
        System.out.println( --i + ": " + total + " in " + (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000000 + " milliseconds" );
    }

}
```

I've posted this question only after a series of tests.

Comment: If the code is really identical except for the inner loop extraction in a method, I doubt the difference in performance has anything to do with garbage collection. It's probably due to a flaw in measuring the performance, or with a subtle difference in the JIT optimizations. Anyway, without real code and a proper benchmark (and that's hard), we can't say.

Comment: *This is just a sample code, so dont blame me for unnecessary operations*. Please post the **proper code** to do the relevant evaluations. And as JBNizet posted, benchmarking is hard, and you're not doing it properly =/

Comment: There is no way that the GC is the cause for the performance difference, since there is 0 object to collect in that code: you're only using primitives. It's a JIT difference. In my tests on Java 8 on a Mac, the second one is marginally faster (3100 ms. vs. 3400 ms.)

Comment: @JBNizet, Original code posted

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Original code posted

Comment: I stand by my previous comment: you're not creating any new object anywhere, except for the array created when the class is initialized. There's nothing to collect.

Comment: @JBNizet , ok. But do you know why there is big time difference between both codes?

Comment: like I said: the JIT probably optimizes the code differently between both versions. On my machine, the times of both versions are almost identical.

Comment: @JBNizet , For me, Method 2 (Faster one) takes 1400 milliseconds, where Method 2 (Slower one) takes 2600 milliseconds

Comment: It's almost identical for me too - 1257 vs 1258 milliseconds

Comment: @Disco3, I've used JDK 1.8 , Windows 8.1 64 bit. All the time I'm getting ~1300 & ~2500 milliseconds respectively. Strange its identical for few and different for few..

Answer (score 1):

The slower code uses the static temp, whereas the faster one declares a local temp inside the function.

To make the two equivalent, try replacing the line `temp = i;` to `int temp = i;` and then measure again.

*Edit:*
I note your comment that you've made them both use a static temp, and the version that calls the method is still faster. I think the difference is due to the JIT: it perhaps optimises the method first (and then inlines it) earlier than it optimises the inline version. Also, your benchmark method is a bit too simplistic. Benchmarking Java code is quite tricky. See, for example, [Robust Java Benchmarking (IBM Technical Library)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/) for a good treatment of the subject.

By the way, in my case, there's only 0.5% difference in timings between the two cases (3585 vs 3595 ms). When I optimize your code (by moving the call to Math.sqrt outside the loop) it runs more than twice as fast, with a more noticeable difference (1577 vs 1687). (This is on 32-bit Windows, Core 2 Quad Q8200.)

Comment: I've replaced `int temp = i;` to  `temp = i;`. This makes the Faster method to be more faster.

Answer (score -2):

yes in the first loop memory of the second loop wont be garbage collected.
reason for not being collected is dependency,second loop inside first loop is having the dependency on first loop.so the things in second loop is some where dependent on the things in first loop they are incomplete without each other but in second case both the loops are independent one loop is not having the dependency on second loop that's why liable for garbage collection.